# Near-perfect hash on known strings

Tags: string, algorithm, hash

Given a set of 125,000 strings, table size of 250,000 (so load factor .5), and also given that these strings never change, what is a good process for finding a better hash function?

Strings are 1-59 characters long, contain 72 unique characters (typical ascii values), average length and median length is 7 characters.

Approaches tried so far (hash always eventually mod table size)

- (suggested by someone) md5 with linear probing (48)
- Python built-in hash (max 40 probes per search)
- Custom hash with quadratic probing (25)
- Polynomial with prime coefficient, double hash with different prime coefficient, search primes 1-1000 for optimal pair (13)
- Do previous 5 probes deep, then generate an array of size 256 that contains largest contiguous blocks of free space left in table, then use those mod 256 with linear probing (11)
- Cuckoo hashing with three independent hash functions, but haven't found any combination of hash functions to avoid infinite loops

Given that the load factor is .5, is there some theoretical limit on how well the hash function can work? Can it ever be perfect without a very massive additional lookup table?

I have read that minimal pefect hashing requires ~1.6 bits/key, and current best results are ~2.5 bits/key. But this is for minimal (table size = # keys). Surely in my situation we can get very close to perfect, if not perfect, with quite a small lookup table?

Speed of hash function is immaterial in this case by the way.

Comment: Apart from the intriguing theoretical issue: if fast lookup is the goal, wouldn't something like a trie be worth investigating? You are spending some memory for the load factor of .5, so the overhead of a trie shouldn't deter.

Comment: @laune: Space overhead might not matter, but lookup time overhead (several cache misses instead of 1 or 2) might be the killer.  Without knowing OP's specific application, it's tough to tell.

Comment: @tmyklebu Yes, thats what I thought - fast lookup matters, although not the *worst* case (40 - OMG) of probes is the measure, it's the average. But the trie requires an effort that's O(length), and that's something you'll need for the typical hash code computation of a string. I say: give the tree a try and compute lookup time over all strings. Heck, I'd do that if I had realistic data, just for the fun of it!

Comment: Why not use some standard hash like md5 modulo table size

Comment: @laune I am going to do as you suggest, but I also want this question as asked resolved, it's taken on a life of its own for me :)

Comment: @VikramBhat md5 alone will not work (since modulo table size there are many collisions). A probing concept is also needed.

Comment: @Henry sorry you would also need probing , i think linear probing would do.

Comment: The only way to come closer to this grail of yours is by analysing the 125,000 strings and the distributon of characters at offset 0, 1, 2,... It's possible that the naive int derived from the first four characters provides an excellent hash...

Comment: @VikramBhat md5 mod table size with linear probing results in 48 max probes, total probes way over, sorry

Comment: @Henry: Are you trying to optimise average probe time?  Total number of probes?  Worst-case probe time?  Total number of things that have their own cell?  Running time in a certain application?  Engineering a hash table is not a one-dimensional problem.

Comment: @tmyklebu Specifically optimizing *number* of probes in worst case, time is less important, with the constraint that the table size is fixed, bucket size is 1, but with the ability to make multiple passes over the data and/or pre-compute values before use.

Comment: @Henry: Why "bucket size is 1"?  And how would you decide on what the "bucket size" of a hashing scheme is?  In any event, cuckoo hashing solves your problem with good-enough probability.

Comment: @tmyklebu by bucket size 1 I mean there is no possibility of external chaining, this is a closed hash/open addressing system.

Comment: @Henry: Sure, that's fine.  You can partition the cells of the table into (adjacent) pairs, though, as long as you remember to look at both things in a pair.  (This worsens traditional hashing schemes, but it improves cuckoo hashing.)

Comment: Have you tried gperf?  Admittedly, it says it works quite quickly with ~15,000 words ([here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/gperf.html#Bugs)) which implies it'll probably be very slow (to generate the lookup code, but that seems unimportant) and may not work with 125,000, but got to be worth a try....  Separately, can you share your string set (maybe on wetranfer.com or similar)?

Comment: FWIW, cuckoo hashing is basically a way of spreading the pain, averaging out the number of post-collision look-ups, with no focus on reducing or eliminating them the way a perfect hash table does.  What's useful is hard to say as your aim of perfect hashing seems to be for its own sake and not driven by any functional concerns.

Comment: @TonyD: Cuckoo gets your lookups down to two cell accesses in the worst-case and around 1.5 in the average-case once you've built the table.  Insertions are where the pain gets spread.  Perfect hashing gets you down to one cell access.  (Also, I'd suggest posting your first comment as an answer so that it can receive meaningful upvotes.  gperf is a good piece of software.)

Comment: @tmyklebu: even avg 1.5, worst 2 may feel painful if you're seeking on disk, which is why the question's insistence on near-perfect hashing has some merits.  Claiming an "answer" for something as trivial as mentioning gperf seems a bit OTT, but feel free to make mention of it in yours if you like.  Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you thought about using two independent hash functions?  Variants of cuckoo hashing can build hash tables with surprisingly high load factors using only two hash functions.

Unmodified cuckoo hashing (each item hashes to exactly one of its two locations) attains a load factor of .5 with constant probability.  If you modify it to use buckets of size two (so each item hashes to one of two buckets, so one of four locations, and you evict the oldest element of a bucket), I believe you can get load factors of around 0.8 or 0.9 without unreasonably long worst-case insertion times.

In your question as posed, there are 250000^125000 possible mappings from strings to table cells.   250000*249999*...*125001 of them are injective ("perfect hash functions").  Approximate the latter number using Stirling; taking the difference of the logs of these two numbers, you see that a randomly-chosen function will be a perfect hash with probability about 2^(-55000).  Meaning that (with astonishingly high probability) there exists a 55-kilobit table that specifies a perfect hash function whose size is "only" 55 kilobits and also there isn't anything substantially smaller.  (Finding this table is another matter.  Also, note that this information-theoretic approach assumes that no probing whatsoever is done.)

Comment: I wrote an implementation of cuckoo hashing with 3 independent hash functions, and so far I have not been able to tweak them to avoid infinite circular references. Choosing the 'new hash functions' (as mentioned by eg. Wikipedia) is the hard part. Suggestions on this welcome.

Comment: You pick new hash functions when you get a cycle.  Look up "universal families of hash functions."  If you don't feel like picking new hash functions, use half as many buckets of twice the size and with *really* high probability it'll work.

Comment: Ok universal families of hash functions was definitely what I needed to read about, thanks for the tip I'll see where this gets me.